# Swift: passing value to static class property from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm definitely new to Swift and iOS programming so this seems like a fairly easy question/solution and I appreciate any help you can give me.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is:

1. connect to an api using JSON (complete)
2. populate a UITableView using the JSON array that is passed (complete)
3. when a UITableViewCell is 'selected' store information about the cell that was selected (complete: in the same class)
4. store the information in different ViewController's property (NOT COMPLETE)
5. navigate to a new ViewController (complete - I'm using prepareForSegue)
6. using the class variable (from number 4.) update a Button's text (NOT COMPLETE because the variable is 'nil')

//the following function is from the first ViewController before the navigation happens

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // ... a bunch of other code that isn't important
    // sname is currently holding a String value properly based on which UITableViewCell is selected

    let VC2 = ViewController2()
    VC2.player_name = sname
    println(VC2.player_name) // this is printing the proper name which means it is stored correctly in the instance of ViewController2
}

// This function is also in ViewController1
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var svc = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2

}



class ViewController2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var btnName: UIButton!
var player_name: String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // By the time we are to update the UIButton's text, the class property 'player_name' is nil again - meaning the name from the previous ViewController wasn't stored
    btnName.setTitle(self.soldier_name, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

}
```

I understand what is probably happening is that when information is stored in ViewController2's class property 'player_name' the information is only stored in an instance of that class which is deallocated when the segue occurs. So, by the time ViewControlle2 is finally reached, what we are looking at is a different instance of the class.

My question is, how do we make a static variable that I can easily change so the value is preserved as I navigate from one ViewController to another???
Do I have to create a struct in the second class? If so, can someone help me create it?

Thank you for any help you can give me!!!

Comment: You could use a class variable, this is different from your terminology, what you have is a class instance variable. But what you really need is a data model class. ViewControllers should not hold data, that is a premiss of the MVC (Model View Controller) paradigm.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but let's suppose I create a new (model) class that holds the information that needs to be passed from ViewController1 to ViewController2. I instantiate an object in ViewController1 (based on the model), but how do I access this object in ViewController2???

Comment: Instantiate in the model class in the AppDelegate, they all instances can access the data since all class instances can access the AppDelegate.

Comment: Is this the best coding practice to get/set data from the AppDelegate?   `let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let aVariable = appDelegate.someVariable `

Comment: Sure. But it is only a couple lines of code to create a DataModel class. But if you only have one item sure.

Comment: Oops... I didn't mean to put the second line of code 'let aVariable...'  I created a DataModel class, instantiated an object in the AppDelegate, set a property in ViewController1  ` appDelegate.someObject.someProperty = "foo" `  but when I try to access it in ViewController2 using the same technique appDelegate.someObject.someProperty is set to nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake on my part:
What I did to fix the problem was declare the ViewController that I was navigating to (svc)as a class property and then I used the same instance of the class in the prepareForSegue and inside the assignment statement:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, APIControllerProtocol {

@IBOutlet weak var appTableView: UITableView!

var sname: String?
var svc: SingleSoldierViewController?

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    svc?.soldier_name = sname
}
```